# Why Watson-conversation is returning the same default response for any request when I created a post call in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

I've created a sample training data in conversation service and Now I'm trying to create a post call for that service using node js to create a chat application.I created a post call and it is working but not as expected.It is giving me the default response for any call.

I came to know we need to pass the context value which we get in the response to the next call to carry on the flow.But not sure of how to do that. can someone help me in that. Below is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var conversationV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/conversation/v1');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
var conversation = new conversationV1({
    username: 'xxxxxx-1a06-4a90-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    version_date: conversationV1.VERSION_DATE_2016_09_20
});
const updateMessage = (input, response) => {
    var responseText = null;
    if (!response.output) {
        response.output = {};
    } else {
        return response;
    }
    if (response.intents && response.intents[0]) {
        var intent = response.intents[0];
    if (intent.confidence >= 0.75) {
        responseText = 'I understood your intent was ' + intent.intent;
    } else if (intent.confidence >= 0.5) {
        responseText = 'I think your intent was ' + intent.intent;
    } else {
        responseText = 'I did not understand your intent';
    }
}
response.output.text = responseText;
return response;
};

app.post('/api/message', (req, res, next) => {
    const workspace = '254654de-2bfe-423a-92ec-6aa66620625a'; 
    if (!workspace || workspace === '<workspace-id>') {
        return res.json({
            output: {
                text: 'Please check the workspace'
            }
        });
    }
    const payload = {
        workspace_id: workspace,
        input: req.body.input || {},
        context: req.body.context || {}
    };

    // Send the input to the conversation service
    conversation.message(payload, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        }
        return res.json(updateMessage(payload, data));
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

exports.app = app
```

Can someone help me how we can pass the context to make it work..Can someone help.U can run the code in your local to test.

Comment: This is just a copy of conversation-simple?  So it should work out of the box. I would recommend to see that the conversation ID is not changing. If it is, then issue is with your app. if it doesn't then the issue is with the conversation, so you need to debug there.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty Conversation Id is getting changed every time

Comment: If you changed any of the conversation-simple application, then check there. There is not enough to go on with what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you post to the api/message endpoint you need to send the context. The very first time you will not have a context. The context will be created and returned by Watson Conversation and then returned in this response: `res.json(updateMessage(payload, data))`

The JSON object that is returned should have a context property. The caller needs to store that context and then post it in the next call. So, the caller code should look something like this (pseudocode):

**FIRST CALL:**

```
resp = POST api/message {}
```

**STORE CONTEXT:**

```
ctxt = resp.context
```

**NEXT CALL:**

```
resp = POST api/message {context: ctxt}
```

**STORE CONTEXT (EVERY TIME):**

```
ctxt = resp.context
```

Always update the context in the caller with the context returned by the server. Whenever you have a new user you start over.

You're not showing any of the code for the caller, so I'm not sure if that is your issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is what I've done:

```
app.post('/api/message', function (req, res) {
var workspace = process.env.WORKSPACE_ID || '<workspace-id>';
if (!workspace || workspace === '<workspace-id>') {
return res.json({
  'output': {
    'text': 'Config workspace'
  }
});
}

var context;

var payload = {
workspace_id: workspace,
context: {},
input: {}
};

if (req.body) {
if (req.body.input) {
  payload.input = req.body.input;
}
if (req.body.context) {
  // The client must maintain context/state
  payload.context = req.body.context;
}
}

conversation.message(payload, function (err, data) {
 if (err) {
   return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
 }
 context = data.context;
 return res.json(updateMessage(payload, data));

});
});

function updateMessage(input, response) {
var responseText = null;
if (!response.output) {
response.output = {};
} else {
return response;
}
if (response.intents && response.intents[0]) {
var intent = response.intents[0];
if (intent.confidence >= 0.75) {
  responseText = 'I understood your intent was ' + intent.intent;
} else if (intent.confidence >= 0.5) {
  responseText = 'I think your intent was ' + intent.intent;
} else {
  responseText = 'I did not understand your intent';
}
}
response.output.text = responseText;
return response;
}
module.exports = app;
```

If you use visual studio to code, then you can check that the same context is passing through the functions, just clicking in the *context* word. I'm not a pro, but it worked for me. Good luck!